# Selecting one row from MySQL using mysql_* API

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT option_value FROM wp_10_options WHERE option_name='homepage'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
print_r ($row);
```

and the output I am getting is:

> Resource id #2

Ultimately, I want to be able to echo out a single field like so:

```
$row['option_value']
```

Without having to use a while loop, as since I am only trying to get one field I do not see the point.

I have tried using mysql_result with no luck either.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Single Row Query with MySQL and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427235/use-single-row-query-with-mysql-and-php)

Comment: This should work. Your error hides elsewhere. In your file, is there any sourcecode in between these lines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to read single record from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811153/simple-way-to-read-single-record-from-mysql)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try with **mysql_fetch_assoc** .It will returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. Furthermore, you have to add **LIMIT 1** if you really expect single row.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT option_value FROM wp_10_options WHERE option_name='homepage' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['option_value'];
```

Comment: Outed answer. mysql_* is deprecated.

Comment: Solution for PHP 7. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62100523/7082164

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT option_value FROM wp_10_options WHERE option_name='homepage' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['option_value'];

Answer (score 5):

Functions `mysql_` are not supported any longer and have been removed in `PHP 7`. You must use [`mysqli_`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) instead. However it's not recommended  method now. You should consider [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with better security solutions.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT option_value FROM wp_10_options WHERE option_name='homepage' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['option_value'];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT option_value FROM wp_10_options WHERE option_name='homepage'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['option_value'];
```

Answer (score 1):

use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to fetch the result at an associated array instead of `mysql_fetch_array` which returns a numeric indexed array.

Answer (score 1):

Though `mysql_fetch_array` will output numbers, its used to handle a large chunk.
To echo the content of the row, use

```
echo $row['option_value'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one if you want to pick only one option value.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT option_value FROM wp_10_options WHERE option_name='homepage'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['option_value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should get as output with this code is:

```
Array ()
```

... this is exactly how you get just one row, you don't need a while loop. Are you sure you're printing the right variable?

Answer (score 0):

> Ultimately, I want to be able to echo out a signle field like so:
>
> ```
>    $row['option_value']
> ```

So why don't you? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me..

```
$show = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM wp_10_options WHERE
 option_name='homepage' limit 1"); $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($show);
 echo $row['data'];
```

Answer (score 0):

is this is a WordPress?
You shouldn't do it like you've done! 
To get option from DB use [`get_option`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)!

Answer (score 0):

this shoude work

```
    <?php

require_once('connection.php');

 //fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "select  id,fname,lname,sms,phone from data";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));

    //create an array
    $emparray = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
   $row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

} $emparray[] = $row;
         echo $emparray ;
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

make sure your ftp transfers are in binary mode.