# I can't show by database single row data?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to show database single row data by unique_id. But i can't.

my query is...

```
"SELECT * FORM `signup` WHERE `uniqueId`=" . $singleRowUniqId
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This probably has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: and what problem is there? use `LIMIT 1` in query too

Comment: Certainly that is possible and your query looks like a straight forward approach. So maybe you need to add some additional information for us to understand your issue. What is the actual result you get back? What value does `$singleRowUniqId` hold? How is the database table defined? And what data does it contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this query. your query is wrong, use this query.

```
 "SELECT * FROM `signup` WHERE `uniqueId`=" . $singleRowUniqId
```

Comment: yes..! is't working. my query was wrong.

Comment: @AbuBakarBelal Note that your SQL query is most likely vulnerable.

Comment: where is difference? if you are going to say `FROM` and `FORM` then that's silly

Comment: he using (FORM) but need to you use "FROM".

Comment: If so, why don't you say so in your answer? Why this "guessing game"?

Comment: @Anant ameenulla0007 explains it... As for lyasin, you should always provide some explanation of your answers. "use this code" doesn't help people learn, and will likely make them try to get other people to write their code them, as that is what "use this code" is doing.

Comment: @Tyler  don't you think that typo gave an error to OP?

Comment: @Belal checkout this article for more info about mysql select query.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427235/use-single-row-query-with-mysql-and-php

Comment: Thanks to all for helping me. Hope again will help me as like today.

Comment: @Anant, yea I do... Why would you think otherwise? I did say ameenulla points out the typo, and the comment about "use this code" doesn't say anything about the typo...

Comment: @Tyler  no what i am trying to say that  why this TYPO mistake didn't raise any error to OP like:-`Syntax error In query near.....`? Isn't it strange?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like, it's a typo. Change `FORM` to `FROM`.

Ultimately, it would be like `select columnNames from tableName where ColumnId='$variableId'`

Answer (score 3):

This query should solve you problem (as others said) but I additionally added `mysql_escape_string` to deny sql injection:

```
"SELECT * FROM `signup` WHERE `uniqueId`= ".mysql_escape_string($singleRowUniqId)
```

Answer (score 1):

You misstyped "FORM" insteed "FROM"